# Single quotes are added in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am running the following bash script. When I use variables with whitespaces, when I use them, single quotes are added. It is not the result that I expect.

My scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
KEY="x"
VALUE="b c"
VARS="$KEY=\"$VALUE\""

KEY="y"
VALUE="d e"
VARS="$VARS $KEY=\"$VALUE\""

env $VARS printenv
```

When I run it in debug mode I get this result

```
+ KEY=x
+ VALUE='b c'
+ VARS='x="b c"'
+ KEY=y
+ VALUE='d e'
+ VARS='x="b c" y="d e"'
+ env 'x="b' 'c"' 'y="d' 'e"' printenv
env: c": No such file or directory
```

But I need the following result:

```
env 'x="b' 'c"' 'y="d' 'e"' printenv
```

How do I prevent single quotes from being added?

When I run this line, It works well: `env x="b c" y="d e" printenv`

Thanks

Comment: The debug mode adds the quotes to show you the results of word splitting. No quotes were actually added anywhere.

Comment: Since you're using Bash, it looks like you actually want to use an __array__ variable instead of `$VARS`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to quote the `$VARS` variable since it contains spaces:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -x
KEY="x"
VALUE="b c"
VARS="$KEY=\"$VALUE\""

KEY="y"
VALUE="d e"
VARS="$VARS $KEY=\"$VALUE\""

env "$VARS" printenv
```

[When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: This doesn't work as desired, because the value doesn't get split into separate assignments to `x` and `y`, and the double-quotes don't get removed. What it does is set the variable `x` to `"b c" y="d e"` (including those literal double-quotes).